# Why hasn't the question ban on my account lifted after six months?

Tags: support, post-ban

I keep getting an error saying I have a question ban. The site then shows me a page of why I may be banned and how to fix it, however; when I view all of my questions *each* one is positively voted, and the ones that weren't deleted long ago and have been more than six months ago (after which I should be allowed to post one more question).

I do not understand why my account has received such a ban, or how to remove this ban from my account.

In response to the duplicate thread flag on this post: I am primarily seeking an answer as to why I have not been given the opportunity to post a question after six months?

Comment: Can we assume that you read the [FAQ](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) about question bans?

Comment: Yes I have been reading on them for past hour. But one portion states that  the ban would be lifted after 6 months(my last question was asked more than 6 months ago) @theB

Comment: Also I have always listened to the moderators and edited questions when necesary, and at least 2 of my questions that were deleted after receiving help from others, where regrettably recommended by moderators due to them divulging security information in regards to a PCI-PADSS application.

Comment: I searched for all 6's on the entire post and I found no "ban would be lifted after 6 months" anywhere... I couldn't find any 6 on the posts.

Comment: @Braiam   "you'll get the chance to ask a new one 6 months after your last question. " in the help page for question bans

Comment: That doesn't means that your ban will be lifted, it means that you have another shot, and if you mess it, well, you will be kept question baned for a long time.

Comment: @Braiam, however i have not been given "another shot"

Comment: You're about a week short of 6 months, @PC3TJ.

Comment: @Shog9 The latest question I can se is November 9th. Is there any way I can view ALL of my questions?

Comment: No. That wouldn't be a good use of your time in any case; instead, I'd recommend fixing the ones I linked to in my answer.

Comment: [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33449017/alternating-ciphers-block-cipher-and-stream-cipher) is really bad and you get it undeleted you need to rework the **entire thing** or it will just get down voted, close voted and delete voted like you would not believe via the *meta effect* same with [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33532818/javascript-prevent-object-refrence-from-being-changed) as well.

Answer (score 25):

Heh... So, first off... There are no bans that "lift" after 6 months.

There's a ban that'll let you ask *one more question* after 6 months, in case you've learned how to ask good questions in those 6 months. But that doesn't lift the ban; it just lets you ask **one** question. If that question isn't *really good*, you're still gonna be banned.

Second, it looks like you've gone through on several occasions and deleted your own questions when they didn't get upvotes. This doesn't help. In cases where [those questions were answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33449017/alternating-ciphers-block-cipher-and-stream-cipher), it hurts - it hurts a *lot*. In fact, any time someone else has put effort into evaluating your question, deleting it counts against you - that's time they're never going to get back, and you've just ensured it was wasted.

- [Someone edits your question to try & fix it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33475890/unable-to-refference-dom-object) & you delete it? Bad.
- [Someone comments on your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33624043/ie-11-out-of-stackspace) to guide you toward improving it and you delete it? Bad.
- [Someone downvotes your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33532818/javascript-prevent-object-refrence-from-being-changed) Well, that's bad regardless of whether you delete it or not, but deleting it doesn't *help*.
- [Someone *answers* your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33449017/alternating-ciphers-block-cipher-and-stream-cipher) and you delete it? That's *super extra double **bad.***

So what's good? **Fixing your questions.** That page you read with all that advice on fixing things, that page is your best friend in the whole wide world. Spend time with it, buy it flowers, gaze deeply into its text and whisper sweet nothings into its whitespace as you memorize the intricate features of its advice.

Then go apply what you've learned.

Comment: Thank you. The only questions that were really active I deleted was requested by the community due to them divulging security information about one of our products. All other deletes where also requested by moderators, and figured would be better than having the community vote to delete.

Comment: I linked to the one that was deleted automatically (#3 in the list) because you could've prevented that from being deleted if you'd just posted the solution you came up with. It's not really hurting you much, but it could've been a win for you if you'd shared what you learned. The rest, you deleted of your own accord.

Comment: Thank you. This is actually the post where I was asked to delete the post by a member of high reputation due to divulging security information(The second to last comment)

Comment: Also I'd love to be able to correct the mistakes in those posts but how can i correct mistakes in deleted posts?

Comment: Undelete them and then edit them, @PC3TJ.

Comment: Okay, thank you. When i tried undeleting it asked me if i wanted to vote to undelete and was expecting it to require me to have several members vote. Didn't realize those that I deleted i could bring back without a vote.

Comment: Also I have started a vote to undelete the question that was automatically deleted, to edit/answer that I found cryptography to be a suitable way to secure this application

Comment: Wait, did you just reveal new information about how the algorithm works?  I don't recall this aspect of it before...

Comment: Pretty sure I've alluded to all of this before, @Will - but we've tweaked the specifics over time, so who knows. I'm *certain* I've mentioned that deleting answered questions hurts; heck, there's even a warning to this effect that pops up if you go to delete such questions. The big take-away, as always, is **fix your crappy questions** - deleting them doesn't do anything to expunge the damage.

Comment: Yeah, I knew deleted questions were definitely part of it.  What I *didn't* know that how much of other people's time you waste plays a part.  Someone who hits "post your question" accidentally and immediately deletes is dinged less than homework vampires who delete their questions after getting an answer--that's really nice.

Comment: And how do you [fix a question that has changed _so much_ as to make it impossible to correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43255053/how-could-i-generate-and-execute-machine-code-at-runtime)? I have three answers on that question, two of which tried to answer the original edits because my question was too broad. Then, of course, meta effect is no help (would have been nice to put it on hold as too-broad) when you ask for feedback as to why the question is bad. Then suddenly, you start receiving upvotes, so which one is it: good or bad question?

Comment: While I agree that fighting crap requires these extraordinary measures, you should not do this unfairly. It is clearly unfair. You could be hard, but you should not be unfair.