# Do question bans become rate limits after a while?

Tags: support, post-ban, rate-limiting

The [help center page about question bans](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) states that banned users can ask a new question after a while (emphasis added):

> If you're unable to improve your existing questions, **you'll get the chance to ask a new one 6 months after your last question.**

What this implies is that 6 months after a question-banned user's last question, that user will be subject to a mere rate limit which is (AFAIK) 1 question per day, therefore coming close to a contradiction with [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/325881) which states that a question ban is in fact an extreme limit that prevents you from posting more than 1 question per 6 months:

> There's a ban that'll let you ask one more question after 6 months, in case you've learned how to ask good questions in those 6 months. But that doesn't lift the ban; it just lets you ask one question. If that question isn't really good, you're still gonna be banned.

Is any of these statements true?

Comment: They are several criteria, one of them is about question quality which is the "question bans", the other is amount of questions asked within a window which is a rate limit.

Comment: It's saying you get to ask one question. That inherently changes the date of your last question. So if that one question isn't enough to lift your block on its own, then you have to wait another 6 months to ask another.

Answer (score 9):

They're saying the same thing; if one is banned from asking questions, they will be permitted to ask only one question within six months, but that *doesn't* imply that their ban is lifted.

The question ban looks at the quality of all questions asked, even those that are deleted.  If the quality doesn't improve in that six months' time, then the ban won't be lifted and one will be able to ask another question in another six months.

I wouldn't personally consider it a rate limit, since rate limits are different by nature and intent.  The site rate limits legitimate usages of the site such as through asking questions via rep and other factors (consult the full [Rate Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899/175248) on Meta Stack Exchange), whereas a question (or answer) ban directly restricts a user from asking new questions or posting new answers until their history of questions or answers improves.