# Question ban is not lifted after positive response after 6 months

Tags: support, post-ban

I got banned from asking questions.

After a 6-month ban, I got a chance to ask one question by lifting the ban temporarily.

[My question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45158191/compile-time-checking-and-where-is-the-main-script-byte-code-is-stored-in-python) got two upvotes and one answer, and it's been one week. Still the ban is not lifted.

According to [Stack Overflow help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans):

> Does the ban last forever?
>
> If you're unable to improve your existing questions, you'll get the
>   chance to ask a new one 6 months after your last question. If that
>   question is positively received, you may be able to continue asking
>   questions; if not, then the ban will be reinstated.

I thought my question is positively received based on upvotes. But no.

Then what does positively received question mean?

Comment: How many downvoted deleted questions do you have? If you're intending to say none, that's almost certainly the wrong answer.

Comment: @RobertLongson I have 2 downvoted questions( asked in 2015 ). And in 2016 my account got hacked and due to some malpractices(done by hacker) I was banned from my account and all my rep(i guess 700) was removed. This is the history of my account.

Comment: Wrong, you've more than 2. How about this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32251477/error-pointer-being-freed-was-not-allocated this and presumably others drag your score down so you're digging youself out of the hole, you're just not there yet.

Comment: @RobertLongson Sorry I didn't see that. But according to ban rule, `If you're unable to improve your existing questions, you'll get the chance to ask a new one 6 months after your last question. If that question is positively received, you may be able to continue asking questions; if not, then the ban will be reinstated.`. So according to my understanding, the ban should be lifted based on the question asked after 6 month ban but not on the previous records.

Comment: _ and all my rep(i guess 700) was removed_ there is no such history in your account https://stackoverflow.com/users/4859791/skreweverything?tab=reputation&sort=graph

Comment: @SagarV Its a very long confusing story.  tl;dr someone used my old email to login and used my main email(SO account with 700) to do something bad. Later my main email(SO with 700) removed and merged with the old email. And I think my ban should not be reinstated based on previous record(SO clearly stated that in `Does the ban last forever?` section).

Comment: @SkrewEverything: Uh, no, the help center *doesn't* guarantee that even a positively-received question will be enough to get you out of a particularly bad q-ban. "If that question is positively received, you ***may*** be able to continue asking questions"

Comment: @NathanTuggy I completely missed **may**. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why hasn't the question ban on my account lifted after six months?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/325880/why-hasnt-the-question-ban-on-my-account-lifted-after-six-months), https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334779/do-question-bans-become-rate-limits-after-a-while

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The ban isn't lifted after 6 months, you're simply allowed to ask a question even though the quality of your contributions is still considered unacceptably low by the post ban criteria.   Your question wasn't poorly received, but adding one question with one upvote isn't necessarily enough to swing you above the threshold for the post ban.

Your new question doesn't just need to avoid being poorly received.  If you want it to get you out of the ban, it needs to be enough to overcome your other negative contributions enough to get you above the threshold where you can ask questions again.