# After 6-month long inability to post on SO, my new question received net upvotes, yet no ability to post again

Tags: support, upvotes, post-ban

So I had to wait for six months for my account to be able to post on SO again. Then I posted a new question, it received some downvotes, but also some upvotes, so the net result was upvotes. Yet it has been several days since I posted that question and my ability to post new questions is non-existent again. What could be the reason?

This question is *not* a duplicate of [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) The latter question has the answer which says

> If that question is positively received, you may be able to continue asking questions;

But my question was positively received and I am not continuing to be able to ask questions on SO. I notice the word *may* in the quote above, yet it is not clear what exactly it means (i.e. what the *idea of a measure* (since I notice in the comments that the algorithm is secret, but it would be helpful (to remove any confusion) to know what the idea is behind this measure, approximately) is of being positively received for a question on SO for a ban to go away).

I also have to respectfully disagree that this question is a duplicate of [Why hasn't the question ban on my account lifted after six months?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/325880/why-hasnt-the-question-ban-on-my-account-lifted-after-six-months) because my question specifically asks about the circumstances in which a question was positively received and yet the ban was not removed, which is not addressed by answers of the latter question.

Comment: @RobertLongson I've read the FAQ, it says "If that question is positively received, you may be able to continue asking questions [...]". My question appears to have been positively received. How much more positively does it have to be received for the ban to go away?

Comment: @RobertColumbia I've read that question, it doesn't give an explanation which Robert Longson gave here.

Comment: Note that it says "If that question is positively received, you may be able...." It says may, not will.

Comment: @RobertColumbia I agree, but yet there is no explanation of what exactly the word "may" means. I.e. what circumstances, how to measure them, etc.

Comment: deliberately so. The algorithm is secret to prevent gaming it.

Comment: @Tom I think my question is not a duplicate of that question because my question specifically asks about the circumstances in which a question was positively received and yet the ban was not removed.

Comment: I don't have anything to add to this specific discussion, but it's very encouraging to see someone trying hard to improve. There are too many drive-by vandals on SO, who ask a crappy question, then disappear into the void. So kudos on sticking around and working to understand how to improve!

Comment: sequence, your argumentation makes no sense. The first paragraph tells your that here is no automated process that lets you out of the ban (like the answer here which _you_ accepted) so it doesn't matter if your asked question is positively received or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing has changed, you're simply still rate limited to one question per 6 months. You've asked that question, if it doesn't do well enough you can try yet again in another 6 months.

As to whether that one question will get you out, that depends how far you are into the question ban. If you're in deep it may take more than one question to get back out again. If you were just on the edge, one question might do it. Clearly you weren't just on the edge.

Given that you've been banned for 6 months you're probably going to need a moderator to help you find old questions you might consider undeleting in order to try salvaging if you have any in such a state. One of them might pop by and add some links to this question now that they are aware that you're keen to improve.

You have [this deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51824472/getting-individual-characters-from-a-sequence-of-characters-in-c) that's weighing you down. As it's closed as a duplicate I'm not sure if there's anything you could do with it other than ask for it to be [disassociated with your account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96732/how-do-i-remove-my-name-from-a-post-in-accordance-with-cc-by-sa-3-0).