# Declined Not a answer flag

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, not-an-answer

I flagged [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58096201/965146) answer as Not an answer. I understand

1. A Wrong answer is also an answer.

Op asked about  Bootstrap carousel and had trouble sliding images. And the answer is:

> You can learn Bootstap Carousel

My flag is declined. Why?

[image]

Comment: Because it is an answer. A poor answer. But still an answer.  There is (in real life and online) instances where we say "RTFM".  Yes, saying RTFM is an answer. It's also a poor answer.

Comment: When you have a C# problem, then answering with "You can learn C#" is not an acceptable answer in my opinion. That's almost the same as stating: "Have you googled the problem" or "RTFM". This answers are especially wrong when the question itself is already off-topic. It's at best a comment, but even that leaves a bad taste.

Comment: So all C# question have answer  `You can learn C#` , All SQL question have a answer `You can learn database`.

Comment: As always, the way to ensure a user that gives bad answers is no longer able to give bad answers is to downvote bad answers. Deleting zero-scored answers doesn't keep anyone giving bad answers from giving more answers.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker No doubt, but this isn't an answer. Maybe if the question was "what technology I should learn next", but it isn't. In fact, even as a comment it's condescending and not nice.

Comment: @JohnDvorak That's where we disagree; and even if we agreed me deleting the answer wouldn't stop it from happening again.  Downvoting bad answers so the user gets answer-limited/banned is a better approach here.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker "removal of x can't prevent further cases of x" never was and should never be an argument against removal of x. Otherwise there'd be no point to the NAA flag.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker why do you think it is an answer?

Comment: As always, both sides have different meanings of NAA. Folks who are saying that this *is* an answer are saying that it *isn't* a comment or another question or something else albeit a bad answer, but it *is still* an answer. Folks saying this *is not* an answer are saying that it doesn't really answer the OP's question it simply points to something else. [My proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377440/can-we-have-the-naa-flag-description-changed) surely would've helped clearing up the confusion when flagging.

Comment: Pretty sure that both downvotes *and* deletion counts towards the answer ban; it's usually a good idea to downvote things that will get deleted regardless for that reason.  It ensures that prolific users posting non-answers will very quickly not be able to do that anymore.  I agree it's not an answer.

Comment: @JohnDvorak Ok, I'll bite.  At the revision I was comparing the question to the answer, it looked like this: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/58095976/2 Scanning the question the OP wanted to have a carousel effect, but it wasn't already clear they were using Bootstrap Carousel. The answer being to the effect of "you can use bootstrap carousel", that's an answer to the horrible state of the question.  After I declined the flag, I edited the question and found ( to my surprise) that they were already using the bootstrap carousel.

Comment: Why do we delete answer posts like "akslhlsakhaflasd" (so just containing rubbish)? That doesn't seem to prevent that users to keep posting such answers, since only downvoting and keeping the answer seems to do that properly.

Comment: @fbueckert I do know that deleted content counts against you if it did before deletion, but I don't think that the deletion itself contributes. Still an argument for downvoting.

Comment: @Tom Those posts often get deleted as rude/abusive for abusing the Q/A format, and that *does* have repercussions

Comment: @JohnDvorak Sorry, I'm having trouble parsing that.  Deleted content counts against you if it did before deletion?  From what I recall Shog saying, deletion counts towards the answer ban, as does downvotes.  So downvoted and deleted posts count twice, at least.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker ah, that makes sense. Thanks. Feel free to post this as an answer, I think it'll be well received.

Comment: @fbueckert Do you have a source for that? Mine's me remembering some comment threads under Meta questions, and I won't even know which.

Comment: Look a code before mod edit. First line first comment "Instantinate the bootstrap carousel"

Comment: @JohnDvorak Hrm.  My memory may be off, because the only [thing I can find](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/325880/) is referencing question bans, not answer bans.  Unsure how applicable that is to answer bans, although it seems logical that it's roughly the same.

Comment: @fbueckert It's important to note that answers can be deleted when the question is deleted (by the roomba). I don't know if they differentiate between types of deletions.

Comment: Frankly I would have flagged that answer as rude/abusive, because it is.

Comment: @Tyler, George would have declined that as well, obviously. I'm a bit surprised he didn't undelete by now.

Comment: @yivi Then I'd probably be right here where Shree is :-)

Comment: @GeorgeStocker What did you see when you started editing the question that you didn't see before during flag declination, that alerted you to the fact OP was already using Bootstrap-carousel?

Comment: @tylerh the comment at the top of the users code that says “bootstrap carousel instantiation”.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Thanks for clarifying. Since that info was present in the version of the question you saw when handling the flag (as the first line in the post, no less) it's safe to say this was an incorrectly handled flag.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The answer should have been deleted (and has been deleted by the LQP review queue). It should not be acceptable to answer any question about a library or language with "You can learn library/language".

It's in the same category as leaving *"You can google the problem"* or *"RTFM"* as answer and does not add any value to SO. Basically, any question can be answered by such an "answer" even if the answerer has no clue what the problem is. And it will also not help anyone with the same problem who finds the question.

If the question would be about how to achieve a specific goal that can be achieved by using X (or to the extremely offtopic question *"Which library should I learn about to do X"*), then "You might want to use/learn about X" might be a (still terrible) answer. But here, op already states that he uses that control and has a specific problem with it.

Even when left as a comment, I would argue that a "You can learn X" comment would be condescending and should be flagged.

As @George Stocker states, it is a good idea to downvote the answer in addition to flagging it, but this is still no reason to decline the NAA flag.

Comment: Minor nitpick: "you can learn X" would be a valid answer to the (extremely offtopic) question "what should I learn".

Answer (score -37):

At the revision I was comparing the question to the answer, it looked like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/58095976/2):

[image]

Scanning the question the OP wanted to have a carousel effect, but it wasn't already clear they were using Bootstrap Carousel.

The answer being to the effect of "you can use bootstrap carousel", that's an answer given the horrible state of the question. After I declined the flag, I edited the question and found ( to my surprise) that they were already using the bootstrap carousel.

Downvoting these sorts of answers helps ensure people who give them are answer-banned if they do it too many times.

Comment: The first line reads "Instantiate the Bootstrap carousel"... I can understand that you don't have a lot of time to read the posts for each flag but that is a weak justification.

Comment: @l4mpi When looking at questions, I tend to scan over the code and go with what they're asking. As an editor, I'm focused on what they're asking, not their code.

Comment: @l4mpi Anyone can make a mistake. No justification needed but "I didn't see it". Getting it wrong handling a flag now and then it's no biggie.

Comment: @l4mpi code blindness to what's written in a code like this can happen to anyone, even if it's the first line. It's an important defense mechanism.

Comment: @yivi Others would get review banned, but that's just "others", right? ^^ :P

Comment: What I do _not_ like about this answer, is that the advice on the bottom seems to weakly imply that flagging this answer was the wrong move... Voting and flagging do not conflict with each other, right? But maybe I'm misreading it. Could you please make it clear in the answer if you think you handled the flag wrongly, or if the flag was incorrectly raised?

Comment: @Tom _Others_ do not handle as many reviews as a mod.

Comment: @Tom this came from the moderator queue; not the review queue.  It has to live in the review queue for an hour before we're able to see it in the moderator queue.

Comment: @yivi Right, I forgot that quantity > quality. Before you get me wrong, I'm not arguing for audits for mods or review bans, or that someone deserves a ban (if someone thinks I have a personal agenda against someone), I just like that people are cheering for review audits and timeouts to prevent bad reviews, but also write "no worries, mistakes happen" all the time when it comes to a certain group of people.

Comment: Another point in case: George argued [50 minutes ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389769/#comment729958_389769) that this is indeed an answer, but his edit of the question (where he, as stated here, found out that OP was using bootstrap carousel) was more than 2 hours ago. So to me it feels like an attempt to retcon his flag handling decision, as the statements used to justify it don't match. Not that it matters much as thankfully the answer was deleted by the community, and I don't think anybody would grill him for saying something like "I misjudged the post due to too less time"

Comment: @l4mpi That's not borne out by when the flag was handled and when the comment was left on the answer (as shown by the screenshot). I do believe it's an answer to the question the OP posed when I handled the flag.  I still believe it's an answer. I also believe it's worthy of downvote. Others have deleted it.

Comment: I'm very sorry to insist, @George, but could you please address my comment? Having clear moderation expectations is very important, and I feel I your answer doesn't really address the key issue here: was the flag raised correctly, or incorrectly?

Comment: @yivi At the revision and seeing what I saw? I woudn't have flagged it. I would have downvoted it and moved on.

Comment: I'm feeling in an extremely literal mindset today: Is what you would do in this case the general moderator stance, and therefore an answer to whether it should've been declined or not?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker That's not the question. Please, come out and say it plainly (and better if it's in the answer than here, comments being not for extended discussion after all): Do you stand by the rejection and think the flag was improperly raised, or think it was OK to raise it but missed some context when handling it? Thanks

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Thanks for the clarification, I incorrectly assumed that you no longer think it is an answer to the question (due to which I tought _you_ were arguing in bad faith). In that case I'll withdraw the assertion from the previous comment, although I can't fathom why you would think "use X" is an answer to a question about X. Also, I think in that case you should expand this answer to spell out why you think the debated post is an answer, and why you think it was better to keep it around than delete it.

Comment: @l4mpi as stated in my answer, when I declined the flag and before I edited the question; it seemed like the OP was asking how to do something (carousel) of which using the Bootstrap Carousel would be an answer (albeit a poor answer -- but still an answer). the analogy I'd use is that "I need to jump from an airplane to the ground without dying." an answer would be "use a parachute" -- but we'd both agree that's not nearly good enough to make the OP successful, hence my comment asking the answerer what specifically about the bootstrap carousel would solve the problem the OP has.

Comment: @Zoe It's contextual on what happens to the flag. If the flag gets handled by the community and three members of the community decide it's not an answer, it'll be deleted before a moderator ever sees it, and this question would be moot (And handled satisfactorily, to the people who deleted it).  If the flag seeps into the moderator queue, you're asking a single person to use their judgment based on what they see; and they're going to process it according to their judgement (as I did).  Humans are not computers. It's folly to treat them as such.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker "use a parachute" is vastly different from [use library X](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251605).

Comment: I tend to treat not an answers rather strictly; because I'm old school like that. Other moderators may not be so strict. I can't give you general advice to never get a declined flag because such advice doesn't exist.

Comment: Ok, I got that, and I think it's reasonable. But your earlier comment says you _still_ think the post is an answer, and I have not found an explanation for that thus far. Or is that _still_ intended to mean _in the context of how you understood that post at the time you handled it_?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker When you came back to meta you seemed pretty intent on moderating comments to no end. Now trying to use comments to elicit a clarification in one of your posts seems to be a futile task. This is rather weak, in general, and particularly coming from a moderator IMO.

Comment: Can you edit your answer and address @yivi and  Zoe concern  rather than back and forth.

Comment: @yivi we try not to moderate comments on our own posts unless they step over a visible line of unkindness that anyone would flag them for.

Comment: "try"? That doesn't sound reassuring

Comment: @Zoe if people stayed kind, I could say "we don't"; but unfortunately not everyone is kind, always.

Comment: I'm not talking about you "moderating" these comments, thank you. I'm talking about you coming back on comments instead of addressing the repeated requests for clarification.

Comment: @yivi No, I'm not going to edit my answer; you may feel free to, but I'm not going to.

Comment: Let me rephrase: "we try not to [...] unless" reads to me "We try not to moderate comments unless [...], but it still happens".

Comment: @Zoe I strive to be transparent. Has there ever been a case where a moderator moderated comments on their own posts? Yes. I know there has (though It'd be next to impossible for me to find it)  Has there ever been a case where a moderator unfairly moderated comments on their own post? Not that I know of.

Comment: Why or how would I edit your answer, if I do not know what you think? It would be improper. I am not going to put words in your mouth. Is that what you suggest? What would be the sense of that? I really do not understand this. You just flat out rejecting to clarify a very simple question and  this kind of confusing response it's borderline disrespectful. I'm not sure what are your goals here, nor what you expect from users here. We have no recourse but to ask, and you are simply going to ignore questions just because?

Comment: @yivi A minute to deletion wasn't enough - I'm 99% sure George meant to ping [Shree](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389769/declined-not-a-answer-flag/389771?noredirect=1#comment730010_389771). But even then, I do agree with you.

Comment: @Zoe I'm replying to _"yivi No, I'm not going to edit my answer; you may feel free to, but I'm not going to_". I believe that comment was meant for me.

Comment: @yivi Yeah, that's the comment I meant too. You don't appear to have mentioned editing, but an earlier comment did. George appears to reply to comments (that need replying of course) in order. I might be wrong of course.

Comment: Smells like some thing  burn and smell bad as usual.  As always good luck for your modration.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Look, I get that all moderators have their own style and all that, and mostly everyone knows mods make mistakes from time to time. You haven't directly addressed that, nor have you directly addressed everything else. All you need to reply is "yes" or "no". You said you check by context - so append "in this case" somewhere. We don't know what you intended, nor will we if you don't just come out and say it. I have a feeling posts like these will keep happening otherwise. We've already got enough borked communication - let's not make it worse.

Comment: @Zoe I hadn't seen Shree's comment, but the the comment I quoted could be addressed to either of us, since it talks about the same thing and the same original point of contention. No, George is not going to clarify anything. Personally, I don't think that's an appropriate behaviour for a sitting mod. I find it quite offensive.

Comment: @yivi my last comment is my final try. SE is doing more or less the same thing George is, just on a significantly larger scale. Anyway, if it doesn't help, we'll just have to accept increasing flag declines on valid posts and just move on. There's far too many cases like these to keep continuing like this. At least for me.