# Should this answer be converted to a comment now?

Tags: discussion, specific-answer

Take the following answer:

> [image]

As the comment beneath it remarked:

> Sadly, all the links are now dead, or point to dead download links.

So I tested each link and then edited out the useless content and we're left with:

> [image]

What we're left with looks more inline with a comment. The NAA flag states:

> **This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question.** It should possibly be an edit, **a comment**, another question, or deleted altogether.

(emphasis mine)

It's way too generic now and could be compared with a "why don't you Google it?" comment.

Should I flag this as NAA for it turned into a comment or should I use a custom flag?

Alternatively, should it just be left as is?

Comment: A mod will be involved anyway (IIRC, posts with a deletion outcome in VLQ gets sent to a mod to evaluate deletion if the score is > 0)

Comment: Were any of those sites cached in the wayback machine? A better option would've been to replace the links, in that case...

Comment: @Cerbrus good point. I never thought of that. The only link which was active was a blog post which had within the post a separate download link to a ZIP file and that link was down.

Comment: [this recent discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/389769/839601) seems related. "You can learn Bootstrap Carousel.."

Comment: It's an answer from 2009, quite a long time ago. I don't generally give much attention to content about Javascript from that time period, both as a consumer and as a curator. There is an invisible "too old" stamp on it. A minimally useful answer to someone using really old technology maybe, they're still around. The message behind the answer is still clear even if all the links are dead; don't roll your own. There is pre-existing stuff you can use, go look for it.

Answer (score 2):

Were any of those sites cached in the wayback machine? A better option would've been to replace the links, in that case...

Whatever you do, don't flag it as "NAA". A incomplete attempt at answering the question is still an attempt at answering the question.

If none of the links can be "fixed", you're left with a bad answer. Bad answers get downvoted, but could be converted to a comment through a custom mod flag...

---

I've taken the liberty to [restore](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1388665/revisions) two of the 3 links. I couldn't find a result for the 3rd one.

Comment: Whatever happened to link-only answers being bad? This is not an answer; this is "[your answer is in another castle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/194720)"; this is the sign pointing to the apple.

Comment: Love this answer. Instead of deleting things, work to improve them to be useful.

Comment: @HereticMonkey: that doesn’t mean we should simply discard whatever value the answer had. You can still downvote it for being link-only, but just deleting the links doesn’t feel right to me.

Comment: So we preserve the tiny value the answer had, links to password strength plugins, by updating those links to obviously-no-longer-maintained plugins? I'm squinting really hard, but just not seeing the value there...

Comment: A link only answer is certainly "very low quality".

Comment: @Raedwald: I never said they weren’t.

Comment: @HereticMonkey: the restored value is the names of the plugins, which may well still exist. If the link is a blog post about the plugin, the blog may be completely unrelated to the plugin...